# Is there a program/script to throttle the CPU temperature when it passes a certain threshold in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cpu, cooling, temperature

I've been using [this script](http://seperohacker.blogspot.com/2012/10/linux-keep-your-cpu-cool-with-frequency.html) on Ubuntu to manage my CPU temperature. This script slowly throttles your CPU once it exceeds a certain threshold and unthrottles it as it gets below that threshold. This works well for me, but I want something that works similarly on windows.

I use an Intel CPU, but the intel extreme tuning utility doesn't allow changing the throttle temperature. As far as I can tell throttlestop doesn't offer this feature either.

If there isn't a program/script to do this, would it be possible to make a script that does this? As long as there's a way to query the temperature and throttle the CPU from command line this should be fairly straightforward to make a script for.

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) Why do you think Intel's CPU management is insufficient on own?

Comment: I can't find a source on this, but I have heard that Intel sets the throttle temperature based on what should probably get it to survive until the end of the warranty period, but I would like it to last longer than this. I have a new-ish laptop where the CPU doesn't throttle until it gets to 100C, which it easily gets to under a stress test or during gaming that really utilizes my CPU. 100C seems way too high.

Comment: Just google 'proc hot' for the specific figures on any given CPU. That's the high-tide for temperature, at which they can run all day. Any further fiddling is equivalent to deciding you don't like how hot your car engine runs. If your machine is failing to stay within proc hot, of course, that is a mechanical issue, not Intel's fault.

Comment: Intel claims that 100C is "safe", but I don't want it to get that hot because I am not certain the parts around it are safe to get to 100C, 100C is hot enough to burn me, and I am worried a temperature can be "safe" but still reduce the life of my CPU.

Comment: So... you've decided you think you know better than Intel & are looking for a solution to support that theory... Good luck.

Comment: I'm not claiming that intel is wrong about the temperature that is safe for the CPU, but I can't find a source for intel claiming that the safe temperature for the CPU is safe for the parts around it or that it doesn't reduce the life of the CPU. Also, no matter what intel claims, when my CPU gets to 100C parts of my computer are too hot to touch.

Comment: Then you have a hardware problem - design &/or airflow issue. When compiling or compressing video, my machine will sound like it's about to take off with all 6 fans running at full tilt, but it stays within 1°C of proc hot & can sit there for hours without any ill effects. The machine is about to reach its 10th anniversary... these 6-core Xeons will run forever. I have several of the same machine type, all have been running 24/7/365 for about a decade. They never sleep & reboot for OS updates.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using a desktop? Unlike on a laptop, on a desktop you don't have to touch the case or have parts tightly packed together.

Comment: No, he's not using a desktop. Those are servers and/or workstations. They are to desktops what a Ferrari is to Taurus.  Look, when the designers developed and tested the hardware they included considerations for the surrounding components. The bottom line here is you are operating on a series of bad assumption that have you looking for a solution to a problem that doesn't exist. That said you are free to do whatever you want... But most people here are going to be hesitant to help you sabotage your own computer.

Comment: Also, if the components around the CPU can't hold up to the heat that's something for you to take up with the laptop manufacturer... Not Intel.

Comment: I wasn't taking anything up with Intel, and you can't tell me that my laptop getting too hot to touch is a problem that doesn't exist. The point is, my laptop get's hotter than I am comfortable with, and there is a solution to this problem that works perfectly on Ubuntu, and I was wondering if there is a similar solution for Windows.